# How can I check the current time of a WPF Storyboard before it starts?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'd like to check the state & position of a Storyboard before executing some other code.

```
void doStuffIfAfter5Seconds()
{
   TimeSpan curPos = myStoryboard.getCurrentTime();
   if(curPos != null && curPos.TotalSeconds > 5)
   {
       doStuff();
   }
}
```

However, when I try to call `myStoryboard.getCurrentTime()`, I get a SystemInvalidOperationException with the following information:

> Cannot perform action because the specified Storyboard was not applied
>   to this object for interactive control.

I'm aware that if I want to be able to control a Storyboard from code I need to start it like this: `myStoryboard.Begin(this, true);`  But what if I'm in a situation where I don't know whether or not this storyboard has ever run before?

Comment: what you actually want to do? trigger some action after 5 seconds? or start the animation after 5 seconds?

Comment: Since the question asked is "How can I check the current time of a WPF Storyboard before it starts?" let's focus on answering that question.  That way, if anyone in the future should come across this post, they won't wind up frustrated that we've steered the conversation away toward an unrelated topic.